# How to change Installation directory in Install4j?

Tags: install4j

The application is currently installed in `C:\Program Files\<Application Name>`

We [changed the installer](https://github.com/FAForever/downlords-faf-client/commit/b75203040f0ee1761391b902d7735654e1714222) to install it into `%LOCALAPPDATA%\<Application Name>` instead.

Since `sys.installationDir` is excluded from the loaded response file:

[image]

I expected that the old directory would be deleted and the new one created. However, the application (update) is still installed into the previous directory. Why is that?

Comment: Maybe the uninstaller loads it when u click update existing installation

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Installer->Update options" and deselect the "Detect previous installation" check box.

Comment: This completely ignores the old installation directory. Is there a way to make it remove the old directory and install it into the new one?

Comment: You can change the application ID on the "Installer->Update options" step instead.